# WrongViewCast error: Unexpected implicit cast to TabLayout: layout tag was Linear Layout

Tags: android

I am trying to copy a previously worked version of a tab layout, however since the library dependencies changed, I get unexpected errors. In my xml, I have:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@id/tabLayout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/nextButton"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1st" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2nd" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3rd" />
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

and this is inside a constraint layout. When I try to find this view by id:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
```

I get the error of WrongViewCast. `import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;` I import the correct library. What is the correct way of calling findViewById in TabLayout context?

Comment: Try changing `android:id="@id/tabLayout"` to `android:id="@+id/tabLayout"` . . .

Comment: Thank you very much. I would have looked at the same code for two hours, lol.

Comment: you're welcome my friend . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `android:id="@id/tabLayout"` to `android:id="@+id/tabLayout"` . . .